# Better way of iterating over two lists

Tags: python, list

I have two lists, say `X` and `Y`.

I want to iterate over them, find out the current list I am on and then perform such list-specific operation.

I am doing this:

```
for e in [x, y]:
    if e == x: doSomethingOnElementsOfX();
    if e == y: doSomethingOnElementsOfY();
```

Is there a better way? I don't care for speed, just want to know if there is a better syntax for such a case.

Comment: Can you please show some realistic example? This doesn't make your problem clear.

Comment: If you are going to need an `if` statement for every sub-list, you might as well get rid of the loop and have as many `doSomethingOnElementsOf` statements as sub-lists.

Comment: @user110 Nope. This is no better than the previous one.

Comment: @thefourtheye: Rather, he didn't edit anything at all

Comment: @Nitish: i just have two lists..

Comment: Usually iteration is done with respect to some ordering. In what order do you want to iterate over them?

Answer (score 1):

If you have two lists of the same size you can iterate through both lists in one loop, such as (in Java):

```
for (int i = 0; i < listSize; i++) {
if e == x: doSomethingOnElementsOfX();
    if e == y: doSomethingOnElementsOfY();
}
```

otherwise you'd need to do two seperate loops, such as:

```
for (int i = 0; i < X.listSize; i++) {
    if e == x: doSomethingOnElementsOfX();
}
for (int i = 0; i < Y.listSize; i++) {
    if e == y: doSomethingOnElementsOfY();
}
```

This is a brute force way of doing it though.  If more information was given you can get more appropriate solutions.

Answer (score 0):

The approach I take is to iterate over tuples where the extra element indicates the flag variable, or whatever is different, e.g.:

```
for (should_chomp, cur) in ((True, x), (False, y)):
    complicated_stuff(cur)
    really_takes_code(cur)
    but_mostly_the_same(cur)
    do_the_different_thing_though(cur, should_chomp)
```

Answer (score 0):

Python provides a built-in function called [zip](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) that should do this for you. zip iterates over an arbitrary number of lists at the same time. This should work as long as the lists are the same length, like so:

```
for e_in_x, e_in_y in zip(x, y):
    doSomethingOnElementsOfX(e_in_x)
    doSomethingonElementsOfY(e_in_y)
```

For other more complicated types of list iterations, there's a great python module called [itertools](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) with great functions for iterating over collections in different ways.

For example, if the two lists are different lengths, you can do:

```
for ex, ey in itertools.izip_longest(x, y, fillvalue=None):
    if ex:
        doSomethingOnElementsOfX(ex)
    if ey:
        doSomethingOnElementsOfY(ey)
```